# Jboss deployment structure loading

Tags: jboss

When do modules specified in jboss deployment structure load? At jboss startup or when classes in jars within modules are called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module jar files will be loaded into memory while deploying application, but i think class object is initialized when its called.